# Output PDF files into Zip File using Java and JSP

Tags: java, file-io, zip, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to output multiple PDF files into a single Zip File on the click of a button. Specifically outputting all of the SPEC SHEET's, which consist of a single PDF file each, by clicking "Download Spec Sheets Zip File". Attached is an image to better illustrate this.

[image]

Right now, my code is set up to output all of the SPEC SHEET's to my local Downloads folder as sort of a test (which is working). I'll need to modify this so that the SPEC SHEET's are outputted into a single Zip File instead.

Here's my code:

```
    public void addToZipFile(String fileUrl, ZipOutputStream zos, eclUser user) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    URL u = new URL(fileUrl);
    URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
    String contentType = uc.getContentType();
    int contentLength = uc.getContentLength();
    if (contentType.startsWith("text/") || contentLength == -1) {
      throw new IOException("This is not a binary file.");
    }
    InputStream raw = uc.getInputStream();
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(raw);
    byte[] data = new byte[contentLength];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset < contentLength) {
      bytesRead = in.read(data, offset, data.length - offset);
      if (bytesRead == -1)
        break;
      offset += bytesRead;
    }
    in.close();

    if (offset != contentLength) {
      throw new IOException("Only read " + offset + " bytes; Expected " + contentLength + " bytes");
    }

    String fileName = fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

    String outputPath = eclSystem.getUserDownloadDir(user) + eclSystem.getDirSep() + fileName;
    String absPath = eclSystem.file2Absolute(outputPath);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(absPath);

    out.write(data);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the java.util.zip package (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) or the Apache Commons Compress https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/zip.html to get the Java classes needed to create a Zip file.